# Application of inverse function theorem of several variables

Tags: real-analysis

Let f : R3 → R3 be given by f(x1,x2,x3) = (expx2 cosx1,expx2 sinx2,2x1− cos x3). Consider E = {(x1, x2, x3) ∈ R3 : ∃ an open subset U around (x1, x2, x3) such that f|U is an open map} .
Then prove that E is a proper subset of R3?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn MathJax and make this legible. Don't just post your homework questions. Show us what you've tried and ask specific questions about where you're stuck. Showing no effort is going to get your question closed.

Comment: I calculated the jacobian and it is zero at x=n pi. If the jacobian is non zero we can conclude that f is invertible but converse is not true. How then to conclude? Please help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $x=n\pi$.

Comment: X is n times the irrational number pi

Comment: But $x$ is a vector. The map drops rank when $x_1$ or $x_3$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$  or when $\sin(x_2+\pi/4) = 0$. Is this not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: Consider just the second component of $f$. Write $g(u)=e^u\sin u$. Show that if $\sin(u_0+\frac{\pi}4) = 0$, then $g$ is not an open map in a neighborhood of $u_0$.

Comment: Sin u is not an open map. I don’t understand the significance of u0+pi/4 here. Can you please give some more details.

Comment: You need to compute derivatives.